# Fast FileSize Compare with Linq

Tags: c#, linq, compare, fileinfo

i have two file directories and i want to be sure both are identical. Therefore i've created a query to put all Files into on FileInfo array. I grouped all files by their FileName and want now compare for every group both Files for their 'LastWriteAccess' and 'Length'.

But, to be honest, like i do this, its far to slow. Any Idea how i could compare the Files within a Group over Linq about their Length and let me do 'sth' if the are different?

```
...

FileInfo[] fiArrOri5 = d5ori.GetFiles("*.*", System.IO.SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly);
FileInfo[] fiArrNew5 = d5new.GetFiles("*.*", System.IO.SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly);

FileInfo[] AllResults = new FileInfo[fiArrNew5.Length+fiArrOri5.Length];
fiArrNew5.CopyTo(AllResults, 0);
fiArrOri5.CopyTo(AllResults, fiArrNew5.Length);

var duplicateGroups = AllResults.GroupBy(file => file.Name);

        foreach (var group in duplicateGroups)
        {
            AnzahlElemente = group.Count();

            if (AnzahlElemente == 2)
            {
                if (group.ElementAt(0).Length != group.ElementAt(1).Length)
                {
                    // do sth
                }
            }

            ...
        }
```

EDIT:

if i run only the following snippet, it runs super fast. (~00:00:00:0005156)

```
Console.WriteLine(group.ElementAt(0).LastWriteTime);
```

if i run only the following snippet, it runs super slow. (~00:00:00:0750000)

```
Console.WriteLine(group.ElementAt(1).LastWriteTime);
```

Any Idea why ?

Comment: Do you wanna do something for each file that's different? or just if there are any differences between the two directories?

Comment: The slow part is probably going to be reading the FileInfo off the disk, for each file...

Comment: Do Sth = If the File of the 'Original' Directory has a newer 'LastWriteAccess' Date or different 'Length' that the File of the 'Mirror' Directory, a copy job will be started to replace the File on the Mirror Side.

The Slow Part is the 'Compare' of ElementAt(0) vs. ElementAt(1). If i delete the IF Part the Program finishes 400.000 Files within seconds. If i do it with the current given If compare, it will take 6 hours. Thats why i ask if there is another option to compare like i did.

Comment: I assume you don't care about files that only exist in one or the other directory? only files that appear in both?

Comment: For this Example, yes, i dont care about them.

Comment: How are you obtaining the initial FileInfo array? All I can think is that the actual enumeration isn't being executed until it is needed by the 'if' statement...

Comment: I've edited the Thread, so you can see how i created it.

Comment: I think your buttleneck is your GetFiles call, use stopwatch to find it.

Comment: I've found some strange behavior, see the Edit part of the Topic. And i will also use Stopwatch, maybe i find there another hint.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure this will be faster - but this is how I would have done this:

```
var folderPathOne = "FolderPath1";
var folderPathTwo = "FolderPath2";

//Get all the filenames from dir 1
var directoryOne = Directory
    .EnumerateFiles(folderPathOne, "*.*", SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly)
    .Select(Path.GetFileName);

//Get all the filenames from dir 2
var directoryTwo = Directory
    .EnumerateFiles(folderPathTwo, "*.*", SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly)
    .Select(Path.GetFileName);

//Get only the files that appear in both directories
var filesToCheck = directoryOne.Intersect(directoryTwo);

var differentFiles = filesToCheck.Where(f => new FileInfo(folderPathOne + f).Length != new FileInfo(folderPathTwo + f).Length);

foreach(var differentFile in differentFiles)
{
    //Do something
}
```

Comment: 'System.IO.Directory' does not contain a definition for 'EnumerateFiles'. I also found nothing similiar.

Comment: What version of .Net are you using? I think that may be .Net 4.0 only... you can use .GetFiles() instead - but it'll be much slower in this case :(

Comment: This approach (or similar that use intersect of two sets first) should solve it. The thing is that OrderBy uses deferred execution, so the actual computation is performed when needed. The first elements in IGrouping<> item in the resulting IEnumerable are in order with respect to the source IEnumerable and it may be difficult for Linq to optimize generally (I think it does it in O(n*log n), but it it may happen that it is O(n^2))...